# Dart: difference between implicit interface and abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to understand the use of 'abstract' keyword in dart. If any class when implemented can act implicitly as an abstract class, what does the abstract keyword has to offer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-abstract classes cannot have abstract methods. So, if you define an interface without implementation, you have to use an abstract class.

From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes):

```dart
// This class is declared abstract and thus
// can't be instantiated.
abstract class AbstractContainer {
  // Define constructors, fields, methods...

  void updateChildren(); // Abstract method.
}
```

In other words, an abstract class doesn't necessarily provide a default implementation of its interface.

### Example

A pure abstract class can be useful as a specification (when the user of this class doesn't know or is not interested in specific implementation). One of the common examples can be a repository:

```dart
abstract class UserRepository {
  Future<void> save(User user);
  Future<User> load(String id);
}

class UseCase {
  UseCase(this.repository);

  final UserRepository repository;
}
```

In this example, `UseCase` doesn't care about the specific implementation of the repository (and it shouldn't if we speak about Clean Architecture or another layered architecture approach). It just defines that, for it to work, it needs a repository class implementing this specific interface.

Somewhere in the infrastructure layer, you can define the implementation of this repository, e.g. using `SharedPreferences`:

```dart
class SharedPreferencesUserRepository implements UserRepository {
  @override
  Future<void> save(User user) {
    // Implementation
  }

  @override
  Future<User> load(String id) {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

And when you create a `UseCase` instance, you pass the concrete class implementing the interface.

Comment: could you please explain when is pure abstract class better over implicit interface. A use case/ example..

Comment: @KaustubhDixit added an example